# Setting up parameter for function within Link List

Tags: c++

I created at doubly link list and want to test out my count function within list class. 
the count function is given with a pointer to an abitrary node and count how many nodes in the list.

- the problem I have right now is to set up an variable/object that I can put it in count function parameter in main(). For example, the pointer can be pointing the middle node in the list. basically any random node that user might be pointing such as head->next-next or tail->prev->prev in the list.

````
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class node {
public:
   T data;
   node<T> *next;
   node<T> *prev;
   //node() {};
   node(T newdata):data(newdata){ next = nullptr; prev = nullptr; }
};

template <class T>
class list {
   node<T> *head;
   node<T> *tail;
public:
   list() { head = nullptr; tail = nullptr; }
   void insert_head(int newval) {
       node<T> *curr = new node<T>(newval);
       if (head == nullptr) {
           head = tail = curr;
           return;
       }
       tail->next = curr;
       curr->prev = tail;
       tail = curr;
       return;
   }

   void print() {
       node<T>*curr = head;
       while (curr != nullptr) {
           cout << curr->data << endl;
           curr = curr->next;
       }
   }

   int count(node<T>* rannode) {
       int count = 0;
       node<T> *tohead = rannode;
       node<T> *totail = rannode;
       while (totail->next != nullptr) {
           count++;
           totail = totail->next;
       }
       while (tohead != nullptr) {
           count++;
           tohead = tohead->prev;
       }
       return count;
   }
};



int main() {
   list<int> test;
   test.insert_head(1);
   test.insert_head(2);
   test.insert_head(3);
   test.insert_head(4);
   test.insert_head(5);


   test.print();

   test.count(??)

   return 0;
}
``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ``` ```
````

Comment: The node pointers itself are inaccessible from `main` because they are private members of your `list` class.

Comment: Why does a count function _on the list_ require a (random) node as parameter? As member function, it can just start counting at `head` until it reaches `tail`, doesn't it (or directly access the internal `length` variable that you could consider adding). Why would you pass in a parameter that you don't need, logically or practically?

Comment: Yeah it is very easy If I just count from head to tail. But I am just practicing and playing around different scenarios with object programming. And Thank Varun Nayak, I think that works. I just create new pointer node from List and make it object and point the node in main;